# Operating System not found after installing Redhat 6 on Windows 7

Tags: grub

I have installed Red hat with Windows 7, now I can use the Red Hat OS but not Windows 7 I'm getting boot options as Linux and Other, but whenever I select "Other" boot option, I'm getting message as "Operating System not Found you can reboot with Ctrl+Alt+Del "

Comment: Check you did not accidentally erase the partition: From linux, run `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` (presuming that is your harddrive),  and cut n' paste the output into your question.

Comment: Do you remember which option you chose when partitioning the disk? Something like "Use full disk" or "Use free space non used by other OSes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably not added Windows to the boot loader. Boot into Linux and run

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

That will generate your GRUB config file. If you have multiple operating systems installed, make sure that the command above lists all of them. For example:

```
$ sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.10-2-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.10-2-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-3-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-3-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-2-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-2-amd64
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found memtest86+ multiboot image: /boot/memtest86+_multiboot.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
done
```

Double check that Windows is listed. Now, install grub to the MBR of your drive (remember to change `/dev/sda` to whichever drive you actually want to install it on)

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sdb
```

Now reboot and you should be able to boot into Windows. If you can't, or if the `grub-mkconfig` command didn't list any Windows OS, make sure you didn't install RedHat on the Windows partition. If you did, you'll have to reinstall Windows.